# Geoserver - How to make a psql-backed timestamp that uses timezones

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, geotools

I'm working on an application that extends geoserver and am frustrated as I'm trying to define a *SimpleFeature* that has timestamps that include timezones.

I've tried declaring my timestamp field using:

```
getBuilder().add(fieldName, Date.class);
```

As well as:

```
getBuilder().add(fieldName, Timestamp.class);
```

In both cases, the associated fields that are created in my postgres database have the type *timestamp without time zone*

Ultimately, I'm just trying to get that psql type to read as *timestamp with time zone*, there's a good chance I'm missing a key concept. I'm quite new to this.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Don't know about your application, but in postgreSQL you can do: `ALTER TABLE <your table> ALTER COLUMN <timestamp column> TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;`